# Price error magento shows old (previous) price when I update the price

Tags: php, magento

When I update the price on my magento site something very very strange happens.

E.g. I have a product with a price of 17.96 and I want to update it to 17.99 so I update the price in the backend and save it. When I look at the front end I see magento makes a special price highlight for it. (I have deleted/ de-activated the attribute special price already to be sure that the special price won't be the problem.)

What could the problem be?

I'm running out of options, I have truncated all the price database and log and /var /cache and so on.

Comment: Assured that it's not your browser still caching the page?

Comment: Do you use other caches than the ones refreshable thru `System -> Cache Managment`? Or proxies, like Varnish, for example?

Comment: And which mode does your product price index currently have? `Update on save` or `Manual Update`?

Comment: @JürgenThelen Nope i have checked several other PC's so thats not the solution. I have refreshed many times and also cleaned and deleted the cache complete

Answer (score 3):

Try to re-indexing your products from admin

system->index management

then click on select All button
and select Reindex Data from Action dropdown and click on Submit button and then check your front end.

Comment: I tried this and it did not work for me.  Better luck to others.